# c++ syncing of cin and cout with iostream

Tags: c++

need some help here;

```
  look at this code:
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
{   ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(false);
    while(true)
    {
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        cout<<x<<"\n";

        if(x==42){
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and now this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        cout<<x<<"\n";

            if(x==42){
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i run both the codes,the first one accepts all the inputs first and then shows output; But with same code the second one reads and prints simultaneously
what's the problem here, i cant understand;

Answer (score 3):

The difference is `cin.tie(false);` (which should really be `cin.tie(nullptr);`). It removes the tie between `cin` and `cout`.

By default the streams are buffered, so the text written to `cout` is not displayed until the buffer is full or the stream is flushed, whichever happens first.

But, also by default, `cin` is "tied" to `cout` and flushes the buffer before each input. That makes any prompts written to `cout` visible before the input.